# How to automate data ingestion with logstash pipelines?

Tags: logstash

I'm using ELK in order to ingest, store and visualize data, no fancy things..

Everything is working fine but each time I have new data to ingest I have to execute manually the command /opt/logstash/bin/logstash -f mypipeline.conf

I was wondering how to automate this last step in order to ingest the data in elastisearch each time new data arrive in the inut folder defined in my pipeline conf file?

I'm using the input plugin :

```
file {
path => "/path/to/myfiles*.csv"
start_position => beginning
sincedb_path => "/dev/null"
}
```

I guess I'm missing an important option that would allow to check if new files are present or not..

"discover_interval" or "stat_interval" ? or the sincedb-path ??

thx

Answer (score 1):

The setting you are looking for is `discover_interval` [Reference Here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-inputs-file.html#plugins-inputs-file-discover_interval)

`discover_interval` controls the number of seconds between times that Logstash re-evaluates the `path` to check for new files, it is by default set to 15 seconds. If Logstash is running, then placing a file into the proper directory and waiting 20 seconds should show data from that file in elastic.

If this doesn't seem to be the case, try setting the value manually to something like `discover_interval => 10`. Setting this too low could generate a lot of unnecessary overhead for your process.

Comment: I guess I'm missing something here.. If logstash starts as a service it will be active all the time but then how do I tell it which pipeline.conf file to use ?

Comment: create a service, detached process or run as a daemon, I actually run my ELK stack in docker, but that may be outside your scope. If you have it running as a service just give -f the full path to your pipeline.conf

Answer (score 0):

found it .. just put the pipeline.conf files in the /etc/logstash/conf.d directory , at start all files in this directory will be loaded and executed.

Comment: This isn't really an answer to the question you asked